# findViewById returns null on Nougat, but not Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

In Marshmallow, everything works as it should. However, in Nougat, I get a `void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` error. The `currentWorkoutDisplay` remains null, even after `TextView currentWorkoutDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentWorkoutText);`

The relevant portion of my layout:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentWorkoutText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ... irrelevant code ...

    // Get user preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // Get the currentWorkoutDisplay TextView
    TextView currentWorkoutDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentWorkoutText);

    // Build the string for current workout display
    String currentWorkoutText = currentProgram + currentCycleText + " - " + "Week " +
            currentWeek + " " + "Day " + currentDay;

    // Set the current workout text
    currentWorkoutDisplay.setText(currentWorkoutText);

    ... continues ...
```

Comment: try using `@android:id/currentWorkoutText` in your textview id

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check to make sure your layouts for "normal" and large devices contain the same names!

Comment: if you know the answer . why r you asking to others ?? :O

Comment: I figured it out shortly after I posted, but decided to leave it up just in case someone else overlooks it as well.

Comment: then, it's not the issue about `Nougat` or `Marshmallow`. its about device screen size.

Comment: Well the issue was that I hadn't updated the layout for tablets after I created a new TextView and I was testing the app on a tablet (with Nougat), which confused me. Once I updated the tablet layout, it all worked as expected. Early-morning mistake, really.

Comment: Ooopppss !! ... be careful next time.. Happy coding :) .